# java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_CIRCUMFLEX - Не работает нажатие клавиши ^ (кавычки) на клавиатуре

Tags: java, исключения

Есть следующий программный код:

```
new Robot().keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CIRCUMFLEX);
```

При выполнении программы выводится ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code
at sun.awt.windows.WRobotPeer.keyPress(Native Method)
at java.awt.Robot.keyPress(Unknown Source)
```

Мне нужно, чтобы программа нажала на клавишу ^ (так называемую кавычку). Как устранить эту ошибку?

Comment: Ответ ниже вам не помог?

Comment: Нет. Насколько я помню, у меня так и не получилось добиться нажатия этой кавычки, и я решил заменить её на другую клавишу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_6);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_6);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

Comment: Не сработало...

Comment: Язык на английский переключите

Comment: а во, точно, пасибо